# Does JGoodies binding take up too much time on the EDT?

Tags: java, swing, real-time, event-dispatch-thread, jgoodies

I am using JGoodies binding for my swing components. I have a demanding realy time display in my program that won't update visually when JGoodies binding is turned on. Is there a way to have the binding not hog the EDT thread?

Comment: something wrong in your binding code - you have to make sure that the bindings happens _after_ the time consuming background data collection is complete, f.i. by implementing a custom SwingWorker and doing the time-consuming task in doInBackground

Answer (score 0):

No, bindings are almost certainly not the cause of your problem - all they do is connect things. If indeed execution is spending a lot of time firing binding events, you should figure out what is triggering the events.

I recommend running your program in a profiler to see where in the code CPU is used (if you're seeing high CPU).